# Редактирование записей класса

Tags: c++, файлы, классы

Незнаю, правильно ли сформулировал я свой вопрос, но суть в этом:
Я записываю класс в файл, и передо мной стоит задача: перезаписать конкретную запись в файле. Я создаю новый файл, и записываю все записи с прошлого файла, когда дело доходит до нужной мне записи, я прерываюсь, записываю новые данные для записи, и продолжаю копировать всё со старого файла. Тогда я меняю название нового файла на название старого файла, и очищаю старый файл для возможности будущей корректировки записей таким же образом.
Проблема в том, что оно не работает, как я бы хотел, редактируемый элемент сохраняет и записывает на то же место, что и раньше, а результат(отредактированный элемент) записывает в самый конец файла.

```
    int numbertoedit;
        cin >> numbertoedit;
        if (numbertoed > nof)  // nof - общее кол-во записей в файле
        {
            cout << "Вы ввели неправильный номер полёта.";
        }
        else
        {
            ifstream myinput("textoutput.txt", ios::binary);                    
            ofstream myoutput("filetoswitch.txt", ios::app|ostream::binary);
            for (int i = 0; i < nof; i++)
            {

                if (i == numbertoedit)
                {
                    cin >> number >> type >> period >> destination;
                    myoutput.write((char*)&obj, sizeof(AVIA));
                    myinput.read((char*)&obj, sizeof(AVIA));
                }
                else
                {
                    myinput.read((char*)&obj, sizeof(AVIA));
                    myoutput.write((char*)&obj, sizeof(AVIA));
                }
            }
            rename("textoutput.txt", "1.txt");
            rename("filetoswitch.txt", "textoutput.txt");
            rename("1.txt", "filetoswitch.txt");
            myinput.close();
            myoutput.close();
            ofstream clear("filetoswitch.txt", ios::trunc);
            clear.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно только изменить одну запись, и новые данные того же размера, что и старые - то можно просто перезаписать нужное место.

Если запись добавляется, и место неважно - то ее проще дописать вконец файла.

А так, в общем случае - да, вы поступаете вполне разумно.

Comment: Забыл написать главное, оно не работает, как я написал) Оно записывает редактируемый элемент в самый конец файла, а то, что редактирую не меняет.

Comment: Так вы открывайте его не как `ios::app` - вы же открываете на добавление. Берите `fstream`, режим `in|out`, и используйте `seekp/tellp` и `seekg/tellg` для позиционирования.